# How to block all outgoing traffic from one program on specific NIC?

Tags: networking, iptables, proxy, squid

This might be a stupid question but I was not able to google the right thing to find the answer.

How do I block all outgoing traffic from `eth1` on Squid on the TCP level?

I have used the iptables rule below before when using Squid in Docker, not sure how to implement it without Docker.

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -p tcp -o eth0 -m mark --mark 0x0c10f -j REJECT
```

Comment: Are you asking what filter might be appropriate in place of `-m mark`? Have you considered `-m owner`?

Answer (score -1):

From the squid box, block all outgoing traffic

```
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```